# how to avoid the same username being entered more than once in the php forms?

Tags: php, mysql

i am simply strucked with this ! I need to avoid the same username being entered more than once ..and also the to notify the wrong password if that occurs .. here is the codes : i am a newbie so help me..

```
<?php 
include('include/header.php');
if(isset($_POST['donor']) || $_POST['donor']!=""){
    $msg    =   $productFetch->addproduct($_REQUEST);
}
if(isset($_POST['reghos']) || $_POST['reghos']!=""){
    $msg    =   $recepientFetch->addrecepient($_REQUEST);
    $msg    =   "Hospital Registered Successfully";
}
    if(isset($_POST['hospitallogin'])){
    $username   =   $_POST['name'];
    $password   =   md5($_POST['password']);
    $qry        =   "select * from `hospitaluser` where `firstname`='$username' and      hospitaluserpassword='$password' and `hospitaluserlevel`='1'";

    if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($qry))>0){
        $hospital_user  =   mysql_fetch_object(mysql_query($qry));
        $_SESSION['hospital_user']=$hospital_user->firstname;
        $_SESSION['hospital_user_id']=$hospital_user->id;
        $msg    =   "Successfully Login";
    }
}
$qry="";
if(isset($_POST['hospitalregister'])){
    $firstname  =   $_POST['firstname'];
    $password   =   md5($_POST['hospitaluserpassword']);
    $cpassword  =   md5($_POST['hospitalusercpassword']);
    if($password==$cpassword){
    $qry        =   "select * from `hospitaluser` where `firstname`='$firstname' and `hospitaluserlevel`='1'";

        if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($qry))<=0){
            $msg    =   $hospitaluserFetch->addhospitaluser($_REQUEST);
            $msg    =   "Successfully Registered";
        }else{
            $msg    =   "The User Name Is Alread Exist! Choose Another One!";
        }
    }else{
        $msg="Password Doesn't Match";
    }
}
```

Comment: Add a `unique` constraint in your database, and look at the returned errors.

Comment: i dont see a username in your register part .

Comment: @user2997718 : the username is the firstname

Comment: ok what do you get when you try thid code?

Comment: @user2997718 : When i try this code same username can be more than once and if i entered wrong password notification "Password does'nt match " is not working

Comment: @user3133195: this is a very insecure page: it's vulnerable to SQL injection and using an unsalted md5 hash for the password makes it massively easier to crack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in mysql:

```
ALTER TABLE hospitaluser ADD UNIQUE (firstname);
```

This will create a unique index on the `firstname` column, thus preventing you from inserting same username twice.

For more help -- can you add the code for `addhospitaluser`?